# How can I minimise data sent through a network in a modern FPS?

Tags: networking, first-person-shooter, data, compression

I am aware of snapshot interpolation with the use of delta compression as being a technique used to minimise the amount of data sent in a modern FPS game like Quake 3, but what other techniques are there?

Comment: This is an extremely vague question- giving more details about what data you need to send, and why you feel it's not already optimized, will help you get better answers (or maybe answer your question for you), but as-is, this question is too open-ended. How you can minimize data depends on what data your game relies on, which is completely determined by how you design it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some background research to be able to ask more specific questions. As-written right now, this is likely to generate just lists of techniques, and those types of questions tend to be closed as off-topic because there's no way to select one correct answer. I'd suggest starting with [Jonathan Blow's Inner Product articles on networking, archived here](http://number-none.com/product/) which go from the very basics to some pretty advanced techniques.

Answer (score 6):

When we implemented our networking engine we exploited a number of compression techniques:

1. First we write all of our snapshot bit-wise: bools are only 1 bit
   instead of 1 byte (or more depending on compiler). We wrote a
   bitstream class that reads and writes data to a stream. This saves a
   fair bit  of data all alone when packing flags down. For an example of a
   decent C++ BitStream class have a look at the RakNet source recently made
   available by Occulus here: https://github.com/OculusVR/RakNet
2. We found the smallest way to represent data, bitwise - if an integer
   can only be in the range of 0 to 15, for example, we only store it
   in the snapshot as 4 bits. We perform this range packing on signed
   and unsigned integers, minimizing the amount of data being sent at
   the cost of having to write the data to our snapshot stream
   bit-wise. There is CPU cost here, but the data bandwidth is greatly reduced.
   We do this for enumerations as well - if there are only two states,
   it only takes one bit, for example. We exploit templates here to
   make this easy to write in code.
3. We establish some data types that can be quantized - data that we
   are satisfied to lose some decimal precision to reduce the
   over-the-wire bandwidth. Combined with the range packing we can
   compress floating point numbers down from 32 bits to a smaller,
   range and precision specific level. Again we exploit templates here
   to make this easy to write in code.
4. Delta compression - you have identified this already, but it makes a
   significant impact.
5. We group blocks of data where the delta compression allows
   us to group a number of related, unchanging fields under a single
   dirty bit to indicate if they have changed or not. This reduces the cost
   of sending a bit for each field indicating it has NOT changed. There
   is less of a win here, and one has to be careful about how you group
   them, but infrequently changing fields that generally change in
   tandem are good candidates.
6. We take the entire packet and compress it using a quick compression
   engine - lz4, for example. This reduces the data even more - every
   thing helps.
7. We don't send ANY data for objects that are too far away to be part
   of the local player's simulation and bulk-synchronize those objects
   when the player enters proximity. Some objects are excluded from
   this system such as mission objects, keys and locks, for example.
8. We don't send ANY data that can be reliably reproduced on the
   client. For example, we send animation state and time instead of the
   position of each bone - the client can reliably pose the character
   with that information, saving us the bandwidth of sending the
   transform of every bone (and anything attached to those bones - hit
   boxes, effects, etc). We extend this out as far as we can. As one comment
   pointed out, "the best compression is not sending it at all".

I'm sure there are others, but these ideas should help.

Comment: The big one I'd add is that you should only send data that the client can't reliably reproduce on its own. That is, send only the non-derivable state changes. Compressing data that you don't need to send is still way worse than not sending it at all. :)

Comment: @SeanMiddleditch Good point - I'll add that to the answer